# ajax call failed with error 502

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, node.js, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use DataTable in node.js(Express, EJS) web app. The functionality of this app is to fetch data from google cloud sql and display it in tabular format. The DataTable definition is as follow,

```
   var table = $('#agencytable').DataTable( {
    "ajax": {
            "url": "listuser",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
    "columns": [
        {
            "className":      'details-control',
            "orderable":      false,
            "data":           null,
            "defaultContent": ''
        },
        { "data": "USERID" },
        { "data": "USERNAME" },
        { "data": "CITY" },
        { "data": "STATE" },
        { "data": "COUNTRY" }
    ],
    "order": [[1, 'asc']]
} );
```

It works fine when I execute on localhost. But, when deployed on google app engine the ajax call to listuser, it fails with error code 502. ON the server it is not calling listener.js. Can anyone tell what might be the issue. I don't have any issue when running locally, only on google app engine it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

Got the root cause of the issue. it is because of google CE uses app.js on its own. So, the ajax call was failing. When renamed the app.js to       appserver.js, it works fine.